# ads not showing with AdMob GMA SDK 7.64

Tags: admob, banner, admob-rewardedvideoad

I have updated my new app (on IOS) with the SDK 7.69 version following the message in my google AdMob account "Some of your iOS apps require a GMA SDK update". The app update was accepted on the App Store, including the new apple appTrackingTransparency.
However, the ads (banner and reward ads) do not show, even though the configuration works perfectly with the test_IDs. Also, the ads still show just fine with my older app, which is running ads on GMA SDK 7.61.

The message still appears on top of my AdMob account, saying some of my apps require an update to SDK 7.64 or later.

Do I have to update my other app to the new SDK for the ads on my newer app to work? I don't think that makes sense tho because the apps should not be connected. I have performed the update about 3 days ago, do I just have to wait longer?

If anyone is stuck with the same problem or knows how to get the ads to show, I would really appreciate help. (I know this is not code question, but I don't know where to ask this)

Answer (score 1):

I have still SDK 7.59 from outdated plugin. Recently I published first time Nativescript apps with admob plugin - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-admob - which is outdated. These app were serving via Google AdMob interstitials for 3 days (very low traffic about 200 hits), then I have received automated template email from Google (Subject: Temporary ad serving limit placed on your AdMob account - "We are working hard... blah blah" - [image])

Comment: oh interesting thank you for sharing! in my case no ads were showing at all for about 2 weeks after I updated to AdMobs SDK 7.69 and then ads finally started showing to my users without any action from my side. I have not heard of a limit like what you are experiencing, but my app is very small so I would not reach that limit.